Running a Python script in VSCode opens the "Run and Debug" Panel and then it errors with a pop-up "Timed out waiting for launcher to connect"
I have recently started to learn Programming (in Python) and am using VSCode. I have just restarted my computer and now I cannot run a python script in VSCode.
Usually when I have a python script open in VSCode, I can press F5 and my script will run in a Terminal Panel showing the output of my script (PowerShell 7.4.5).
After restarting my computer and trying to run a script in VSCode, the Debugger Panel now opens and after a few seconds I get a pop-up message saying "Timed out waiting for launcher to connect". I don't remember the debugger panel opening in the past, and my script output would just be displayed in the Terminal Panel. I don't know if restarting my computer ran an update that switched a setting or maybe I changed something without knowing?
Here are the settings I found that might be causing the problem. I used the stackoverflow links listed below to try to find a solution.
Here is my launch.json config
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python Debugger: Current File",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}

In my settings.json I have the following two lines that I thought might fix the problem from other questions answered on stackoverflow:
"code-runner.runInTerminal": true 
and
"debug.internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
Here are all the settings in what seem to be the Terminal section of the settings.json.
    "window.zoomPerWindow": false,
    "editor.fontSize": 18,
    "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 18,
    "python.interpreter.infoVisibility": "always",
    "terminal.integrated.defaultLocation": "editor",
    "terminal.integrated.tabs.defaultColor": "terminal.ansiGreen",
    "window.zoomLevel": 2,
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
    "debug.internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
    "terminal.integrated.automationProfile.windows": {}

I have found and tried the following suggestions on Stackoverflow:
"Then just search code runner run in terminal You'll see an option to enable Run in Terminal feature turn that on."
I made sure this was set to "true" in my settings.
"code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
Cant run a code in vscode, instead of showing it to me in the terminal section, it sends me to the output section
I have opened a Terminal Panel and changed to the same directory as the script I was running and then tried F5 but it still opened the debugger and then timed out.
Cant run a code in vscode, instead of showing it to me in the terminal section, it sends me to the output section
I tried turning off "Debug Mode" but after restarting VSCode the problem persists.
"debug.internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
How to turn off or close debugging mode in VS-Code
I have made sure the console is set to "integratedTerminal"
"console": "integratedTerminal"
Time out waiting for launcher to connect in VS code
I also tried setting
"console" to "internalConsole"
But still I have the same problem. I have changed my setting back to
"integratedTerminal"
I have made sure to close all open Terminals and restart VSCode but the problem continues.
Timeout when I try to debug a python file in vscode

I had a similar problem in the past. My solution might not be what you are looking for, but I just run my code directly from the terminal now using python xyz.py

@oskar. Good idea. I will use this solution while I figure things out or if I have similar problems in the future.

I have come up with a solution that works for me, but it does not fix the problem, it's more of a workaround.
I added a keyboard shortcut to run the "Python: Run Python File" command.
Here is what I did:
Open Keyboard Shortcuts in VSCode  - (ctrl + k ctrl + s).
In Keyboard Shortcuts I searched for "Python: Run".
One of the results was - "Python: Run Python File".
I added a Keybinding of (Ctrl + F1) to this command.
Now when I have a python script open in the Editor and press (Ctrl +F1), a new Terminal panel opens and runs my script. There are no errors and the Debugger doesn't open. Just what I wanted.
As oskar mentioned, I could just run the file directly from the Terminal but I like the Keyboard shortcut.
In case anyone was wondering, here are the Commands and the "When clause" to the F5 and (Ctrl + F5) on my VSCode that are giving the "Timed out" error.
I could change my F5 Keybinding to point to the "Python: Run Python File" that is working, but I hope to get this problem fixed at some point in the future so the F5 key will run the debugger normally.


Hi ElectroCoding, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also can I answer my own question..
, Just a reminder :)

try this
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
{
"name": "Python Debugger: Current File",
"type": "python",
"request": "launch",
"program": "${file}",
"console": "integratedTerminal",
"justMyCode": false,
"logToFile": true,
"pythonPath": "${workspaceFolder}/venv/bin/python"  // replace with the correct python interpreter path
}
]
}

thanks, I added your config and it did not seem to help so I must have something else set that is overriding. The debugger still opens every time and gives "Timed out waiting for launcher to connect".

Hallo, i think if i was you i would just reinstall the IDE or find other one
